# Cannot delete course Google Classroom API

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-classroom

I'm trying to delete a course using the "TRY THIS API" option in https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/delete I get the error:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the request you are making? Also, does the user who created this course still exist? I'm thinking your problem might be related to [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760244).

Comment: I'm looking for the ownerId in adminSDK and it says "resource not found" so you are right the owner doesn't exists, I tried to patch and change the owner but it said only a co-teacher can be owner then I tried to add a new teacher and I got: Precondition check failed FAILED_PRECONDITION

Answer (score 0):

Care should be taken when removing a teacher's account, because, as explained [in the official documentation](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6071551):

> Before you remove a teacher's account, confirm that the teacher’s classes are no longer in use by students or co-teachers. **Removing a teacher account without transferring ownership limits some class functionality**.

Because of this, trying to remove a course owned by a deleted user results in a 500 error, as [reported in Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760244).

In normal conditions, as a G Suite admin, you should be able to [transfer ownership of the class](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/7477648), but since the class functionality is limited, you might not be able to add a new teacher to transfer ownership to. Because of this, the `FAILED_PRECONDITION` error you are getting might be due to the course being in a [non-modifiable state](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors#failed_precondition) ([here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors#failed_precondition) you can see the possible reasons behind `FAILED_PRECONDITION`).

#### Reference:

- [Issue Tracker: 500 Internal Server Error when trying to delete courses created by users that have been deleted](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760244)
- [Before you remove a teacher account](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6071551)
- [Transfer ownership of the class](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/7477648)
- [Request Errors: FAILED_PRECONDITION](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors#failed_precondition)

Comment: there is no way to delete the course then? is there a plan to include a validation before deleting a user? to keep data integration.

Comment: @Diego there is an [open Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760244) to deal with this situation. You can click the star on the top left in this page if you want to keep track of its development.